# How can I plot power of two x-axis?

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I plot a x-axis that just have numbers like 1,2,4,8,16,... (power of two)? 
I want this axis just have these numbers and no other number.
I am a newbee in matlab

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? What's on the y-axis?  Are you talking about axis labels or data points?

Comment: On x-axis I have powered by two numbers and my y-axis is based on my function here its min is 0 and max is 20.I'm talking about labels not data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play with the [axis properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html) of a plot, especially `xtick` and `xticklabels`. The first one lets you set your own location of tick-marks, the second lets you set arbitrary labels for those ticks. Example:

```
x = logspace(0, log10(64), 100);
plot(x, log2(x)) % plot something
set(gca, 'xtick', (2.^(0:6))) % set ticks at 1,2,4,8,...
set(gca, 'xscale', 'log') % scale x-axis logarithmic
```